# cursor css only working on div name and not specific elements within div

Tags: jquery, html, css

The current css doesn't work with the cursor setting. It will only work if I set

cursor:not allowed;

**to the .bar class and not specific elements like .bar p.** My goal as that on each progressive click on the page, the .bar p cursor gets set to pointer and point-events as the element can be come clickable.  This part does work but I would like in the beginning for all of the p elements to have not-allowed as the cursor setting.

```
<div class="bar">
    <p id="income" onclick="redo(0, this.id)" >Income</p>
    <p id="state" onclick="redo(1,this.id)">State</p>
    <p id="rent" onclick="redo(2,this.id)">Rent</p>
    <p id="zip" onclick="redo(3,this.id)">Zip Code</p>
    <p id="roommate" onclick="redo(4,this.id)">Room mate</p>
</div>


.bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: green;


}

.bar p{
    display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3vvLrp75/1/

```js
$('.bar p').first().css({
  'pointer-events': 'auto',
  cursor: 'pointer'
});

$('p').click(function(){
  $(this).next().css({
    'pointer-events': 'auto',
     cursor: 'pointer'
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: green;
}

.bar p{
    display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="income">Income</p>
    <p id="state">State</p>
    <p id="rent">Rent</p>
    <p id="zip">Zip Code</p>
    <p id="roommate">Room mate</p>
</div>
```

If you set the `css` property as `pointer-events:none;` then your cursor won't be displayed.

**Solution explaination:**
Using `jQuery` first `p` tag will have `cursor:pointer;`, if you click then next `p` tag will get `cursor:pointer;`

**Updated answer**
Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3vvLrp75/4/

```js
var clickMethod = function(index){
 index++;
 $('p:nth-child(' + index + ')').next().css({
     cursor: 'pointer'
  }).bind('click', function(){
   clickMethod(index);
  });
};

$('p').on('click', function(){
  var i = $(this).next().index();
 $(this).next().css({
     cursor: 'pointer'
  }).bind('click', function(){
   clickMethod(i);
  });
});

$('.bar p').first().css({
  cursor: 'pointer'
}).siblings('p').unbind('click');
```

```css
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: green;
}

.bar p{
    display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="income">Income</p>
    <p id="state">State</p>
    <p id="rent">Rent</p>
    <p id="zip">Zip Code</p>
    <p id="roommate">Room mate</p>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: those is explains why the cursor not allowed wont show the not allowed because everything else is set to none. How can I get it so those elements dont get clicked until I let them but also having the not allowed cursor

Comment: @Aaron Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/3vvLrp75/3/ . Without `pointer-events:none;` .You need to unbind click and then again bind it back to the next `p` tag.

Comment: @Aaron Did it helped you??

Comment: Slightly, I noticed if your code stops working after the 3rd p element

Comment: @Aaron Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/3vvLrp75/4/ . I will update the answer.

Comment: im going to try a different way of doing this, allowing the first element to be cickable and then when it gets submitted changing the next color css. You can ionly click the p elements if their css is a certain way

Comment: This method worked very well, all I did was a if statement and jquery.hasClass

Comment: @Aaron please accept & upvote the answer, if you find it helpful.